# What is the name of this pâté "container" (image included)

Tags: word-request

Could you tell me how is this pâté "container" called in English?

[image]

Thank you :)

Edit: I am not looking for the exact name of this particular packaging. I know that water is usually sold in bottles, milk in cartons and yogurt in containers - now I need to know the name of "container" used for pâté.

Comment: Most Brits would probably call it a *foil carton*, but because that term is often used for cat food containers, I'd probably use *foil **tub***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "foil tub" evokes only some 3000 Google-hits. I thought it was "tin can", but I apparently was *out to lunch* on this, as a non-native speaker. (0:

Comment: Tub is more usually used for a plastic container of that shape.

Comment: @Chenmunka: I have no doubt there will be *dozens* of containers more or less that shape containing pate in the supermarkets where I live (UK SE). But my gut feel is *most* of them would actually be made of plastic (apart from the "peel-off" lid, which would often be thinner foil).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Agreed, my point was just that your first comment referred to a *foil" tub.

Comment: **Tub** (but not *foil tub*) feels about right to this New York City native.  I can't think of anything else I'd call it, other than maybe just "container".

Comment: In the US, it would be called a **tin** of pate. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tin%20of%20pate%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @TRomano - True, I'd call it a **tin** or maybe a **can** if it were made of metal.  If it were made of plastic, though, it would feel weird to call it that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Americans call a generic metal container for food a "can" whereas Brits call it a "tin".**  (Both are short for "tin can".)  A better example of food in cans is a soup can.  Sardines, also, are in *cans*.  (Hence, *Cannery Row*.)

*Foil* is a very thin flexible metal (typically aluminum) sheet and might be used for the top of a container.  (The kind that does not require a *can opener* to open.)  It is not a very sturdy packaging choice and so the rest of the container would not typically be metal -- I see it used for the tops of plastic containers (such as for yogurt).  Not being sturdy is not a problem if the food contained is perishable, and thus not expected to be stored for long. Sardines would never be stored in a foil-topped can.

The one in your picture looks squat and wide with rounded corners at the bottom, making it look more like a "tub" -- but "tubs" (for food) are usually plastic (example: margarine tub).  They often have foil or plastic lids.

The glass equivalent of a *can* is a *jar*.  A jar that is tapered to a small opening at the top is a *bottle*.  You also already know about *cartons*.

All of these are *containers*, and people refer to *yogurt containers* because they can't quite figure out what sub-category those belong in.  (It's like with "parking structure" used to refer to a multi-level above-ground garage.)

Bon appétit!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the metal used, simply enough it is an "aluminum can", "tin can", or "steel can".  [Probably tin.](https://www.google.com/search?q=tin+can+pate)  Even though it may not look like a traditional can, it is still a can.  It is probably a non-standard shape for marketing/branding purposes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminum_can

http://www.dreamstime.com/stock-image-pate-closed-tin-can-image26651531

http://www.riocaima.pt/en/canned-pate-28gr.html